# WEBrick DocumentRoot for MP4s

Tags: ruby, http, webrick

I have a very simply ruby script to Serve the file system from one computer over the local host to my other PCs. I want MP4s to be watchable directly in the browser window. I've added the mime_type for mp4's, which has set the content-type to `video/mp4` as required instead of the default `octet-stream`, however the videos are still unplayable?

```
require 'webrick'

mime_types = WEBrick::HTTPUtils::DefaultMimeTypes
mime_types.store 'mp4', 'video/mp4'

server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 12345,
                            :SSLEnable => false,
                            :DocumentRoot => '/',
                            :AccessLog => [],
                            :MimeTypes => mime_types)
trap 'INT' do server.shutdown end

server.start
```

The server indicates it's OK:

[image: network trace]

But the video isn't play-able?:

[image: video not playable]

How does one fix this issue? Is this a WEbrick issue?

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Is this serving a static file? Is it aware it is binary and no CRLF conversion should be done? Check with `curl` that you're getting the same file back, especially the same length.

Comment: @tadman not entirely sure how to check with curl, but typing `curl <url>` doesn't respond with anything (curl hangs/doesn't resolve) from my windows OS console. Additionally, I don't know for sure but `video` and `mp4` tags are relevant as these were my search terms in google, so think they should be included. Also not sure how I can copy the header responses as code re: your first comment... All the code required for own testing is supplied in the main post.

Comment: `curl URL` where `URL` is the exact one shown in that "Request URI" debugging screen.

Comment: @tadman yeah, in that case, curl hangs indefinitely / doesn't resolve.

Comment: The "doesn't resolve" part for "localhost" makes no sense. Are you sure?

Comment: @tadman my thoughts exactly, I am 100% sure it's not resolving though. Interestingly I did try with a tiny video 282KB (previously it was 8MB) and it appears chrome can render this video. So it may just be a speed issue, which also makes little sense given it's localhost... Curl doesn't respond even on the smallest file though, for some reason...

Comment: Webrick isn't the best option, in fact it might be the worst, so if you have *any* alternative, I'd recommend that. A modern example is [Falcon](https://github.com/socketry/falcon).